# Why pointer of pointers are declared with different no. of asterisk when their size is same

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Size of 'pointer' is always same (4/8B/something else) according to the the architecture or compiler.

```
int** b = &pointer;
int***c = &b;
```

sizeof(b) and sizeof(c) are same,and so we could dereference them the same way.
Shouldn't it be like that if a pointer points to another pointer or pointer of pointer we just need to declare it with two stars.

Comment: First of all, the size of a pointer is **not** always the same... And not all pointers are of the same size. Not even on the same architecture.

Comment: And how would you know that `***c = 0;` is valid but `******c = 0;` is not, if you declared it all with two asterisks?

Comment: Also, since you're using the "C++" style of putting `*` next to the type and not next to the name you're missing something important. The declarations say that `*a` is an `int`, and `**b` is an `int` and so is `***c`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Beg your pardon, "C++ style"?

Comment: @StoryTeller because that style really was popularized with C++ `&` et all... [And Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Eh, I'm pretty sure that flame war predates C++ itself. Besides, the only place where I've seen it be only one way and not the other (in both C and C++) is in function return types. And Bjarne, bless him, does not speak for all of us.

Comment: They dereference to produce different types. One dereferences to an `int` whereas the next dereferences to a pointer `int*` and so on...

Comment: @StoryTeller you must also remember that C++ and Stroustrup's opinion predates most C programs ;-)

Comment: If it did not matter do you think it would have been implemented like that? Right; so there clearly must be a reason.

Comment: @JespherJuhl- i know that there must be a reason for that and i want to know that reason.

Comment: With that concept of your's why use types at all? Why not make it all integers and blocks of memory? Type checking is for the weak, let's go back to Assembler language. Said that: you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: why am i getting so many downvotes for asking a logical question?

Comment: @shobhit: There are a number of people following the [C] tag who disfavor elementary questions about C. Additionally, down votes may be related to perceived usefulness of the question to other users rather than the quality of the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it matters. Pointer arithmetic solely depends on what it points to. For example `int(*p)[2]` and `int *p` both of them are different. The same way `int **p` and `int ***p` is different. You might think even if the `sizeof (int*)` and `sizeof(int**)` is same - ***it is not logical to lose the multiple indirection information***. It is helpful for having correct pointer arithmetic. (And in case their size same it will be same but pointer arithmetic will be no problem but it will be problematic in other way - see second para for the problem).

Note these are quite helpful for us to write - think of a system where you will have the responsibilty of writing the correct code for dereferencing the variable correct number of times. You have to keep in mind the where it points to? whether it's an address of a variable or pointer to a pointer. This will simply make C programming nothing other than writing down in the underlying assembly language - where we will have to deal with raw addresses. And then think, to remember how many times you need to dereference you need to maintain some metadata along with that variable - precisely what are being stored by compiler by preserving the type information `int*` or `int**`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: I edited...thanks for the earlier comment.

Comment: @coderredoc thnx now it makes sense.

Comment: @shobhit.: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: that’s not guaranteed.  It’s true on x86 and some other commodity hardware, but there are some oddballs out there where different pointer types *do* have different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your example:

```
int* a = &integer
int** b = &a;
int*** c = &b;
```

They are all *different types*. They are all *pointers* but they point to different *types* of pointer.

The first is a *pointer to integer*.

The second is a *pointer to a pointer to an integer*.

The third is a *pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an integer*.

This is important when it comes to looking at what the pointer points at (dereferencing).

If I do:

```
*b; // what is that?
```

Do I get an integer from that? No! I get out what I put in:

```
int** b = &a;
```

I get `a` which is a *pointer to integer* which is **not** an `int`, it is a *pointer to int*.

If I want to get to the `int` I have to dereference again:

```
**b; // now I located the integer
```

So `*b` is an `int*` and `**b` is the original `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> in above lines 2 and 3 both variable pointer points to some address

Right.  `b` has the address of (points to) `a`, and `c` has the address of `b`.

I think what you're asking is that since `b` has type "pointer to pointer to something" and `c` has type "pointer to pointer to something", then `b` and `c` will have very similar representations and will use very similar code.  And that's true... but.

Pointer arithmetic in C is about more than just the machine language that's generated.  We don't just care that `b` is a "pointer to pointer to something", because *we need to know the type of the value that will result if we dereference it*.  Since `b` is, in fact, a pointer to pointer to `int`, then `*b` (that is, the "contents of" `b`, the value we get when we dereference `b`) is a pointer to int.  `*c`, on the other hand, is a pointer to pointer to int.  So `b` and `c` are *not* the same type.

If you really really wanted to, in practice you *could* make use of your belief that all pointers to pointers have basically the same type by using `void **` as a "generic pointer to pointer" type.  But you'd have to use a while bunch of extra, explicit casts:

```
int integer = 5;
int *a = &integer;
void **b, **c;       // "generic pointer to pointer"

b = (void **)&a;
c = (void **)&b;

printf("the int: %d\n", integer);
printf("via pointer: %d\n", *a);
printf("via 2-level pointer: %d\n", **(int **)b);
printf("via 3-level pointer: %d\n", ***(int ***)c);
```

But this code is harder to write, harder to read, and harder to think about.  And it is not strictly portable or in conformance with standards, either.

(You might ask, "Realistically, on what kind of machine would it not work?", and I confess that I cannot name one; it would work fine on any machine that we currently consider practical and conventional.  But the code is still harder to write, harder to read, and harder to think about.)